# How to get identical byte[] in C# and Java

Tags: java, c#, arrays, aes

*TLDR:* Java is **signed**, c# is **unsigned**. `Byte[]` values are different, how to solve this. How can I convert either side to the other?

Values are of `"Hello World"` `MD5` hashed and then converted to `bytes`

**Java:**

```
-79, 10, -115, -79, 100, -32, 117, 65, 5, -73, -87, -101, -25, 46, 63, -27
```

**C#:**

```
177, 10, 141, 177, 100, 224, 117, 65, 5, 183, 169, 155, 231, 46, 63, 229
```

I use the `byte[]` to encrypt using `AES` on both sides but the passwords **never match.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920044/how-can-you-generate-the-same-md5-hashcode-in-c-sharp-and-java

Comment: The values aren't different. They're *represented* differently. You can be sure that the bits are exactly same.

Comment: My hashes match, my bytes don't. I don't see anything helpfull in that post.

Comment: My post is targeted at Sarathy, sorry Kayaman.

Comment: Are you trying to write something like `byte[] b = {177, 10, 141, 177, 100, 224};` in Java source code?

Comment: No, that wouldn't work. A file gets encrypted on c# side, the password bytes are then sent to Java in Hex format. When Java tries to decrypt the file it can't because the byte[] don't match.

Comment: @user5581557, that's wrong.  If you're having problems decrypting the file in Java, it's not because Java uses signed bytes.

Comment: @LouisWasserman You are correct, Java handled the bytes for me when decrypting and it was successful, the problem was with encoding which I fixed by converting the decrypted data to UTF-8.

Answer (score 8):

The bytes have identical values, they are just printed differently.

If you would like to ensure that bytes with negative values are displayed as positive numbers, add 256 and take modulo 256, like this:

```
for (byte b : byteArray) {
    int n = (b + 256) % 256;
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

Similarly, if you would like to bring your values above 128 into the proper range of byte, you can cast them to truncate the upper bytes and get negative values, or if you prefer you could subtract 256:

```
for (int n : byteValuesAsInt) {
    byte b1 = (byte)n;
    byte b2 = n >= 128 ? n-256 : n;
}
```

Comment: My objective is not to view the bytes, its to use them. In Java I cannot insert the values into a byte[] as It's unsigned.

Comment: Of course you can. Just cast them down to a byte. Whether it will end as a negative number is not relevant - the bytes representation is the same.

Comment: Could you show an example of "casting down to a byte" please.

Answer (score 3):

Java uses *signed* bytes, while C# uses *unsinged* ones. To compare *strings*, let's convert Java representation to C# one:

```
  String java = 
    "-79, 10, -115, -79, 100, -32, 117, 65, 5, -73, -87, -101, -25, 46, 63, -27";

  String cs = String.Join(", ", java
    .Split(',')
    .Select(c => int.Parse(c))
    .Select(x => x < 0 ? 256 + x: x));

 // 177, 10, 141, 177, 100, 224, 117, 65, 5, 183, 169, 155, 231, 46, 63, 229
 Console.Write(cs);
```

As you can see the strings are now *equal*.

**EDIT:** If you're given java *string*, and you want to have C# `byte[]`:

```
 byte[] cs = java
   .Split(',')
   .Select(c => int.Parse(c))
   .Select(x => (byte) (x < 0 ? 256 + x: x)))
   .ToArray();
```

Comment: Okay thats perfect, but how can I use that string (result) in a function which takes a byte[] as a parameter?  ex: decrypt(byte[],byte[])

Comment: @user5581557: if you're given Java *string* (since there're negative values in the Java result you can't have `byte[]` in C# directly) you can convert it into c# `byte[]` via *Linq* (see my edit)